# Anaconda Navigator is not opening and anaconda prompt is throwing a weird error

Tags: conda, anaconda3

I installed anaconda a few days back and it worked great, I even created a separate environment for TensorFlow but now nowhere anaconda navigator is not launching and Anaconda prompt gives the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anurag\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\Anurag\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 118, in main
    from ..exceptions import conda_exception_handler
  File "C:\Users\Anurag\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .models.channel import Channel
  File "C:\Users\Anurag\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\models\channel.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ..base.context import context, Context
  File "C:\Users\Anurag\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 58, in <module>
    from ..common._os.linux import linux_get_libc_version
  File "C:\Users\Anurag\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\_os\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .windows import get_free_space_on_windows as get_free_space
  File "C:\Users\Anurag\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\_os\windows.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ctypes import (POINTER, Structure, WinError, byref, c_ulong, c_char_p, c_int, c_ulonglong,
  File "C:\Users\Anurag\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

Please help me with this issue.